# How do you convert a string containing an operation into a numerical value

Tags: python, math, calculated-columns

I need to convert a string variable in the form of 'x / y', where x and y are arbitrary values in this string,  into a numerical value. I'd assume that, using python, simply doing `float('x/y')` would allow for the interpretation of the division operation and thus yield a numerical value as the response, but instead, I am met with the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7/100' (7 and 100 were the arbitrary values here)

Which suggests that this method is invalid. Is there any other way of doing this ? I thought of converting 'x' into an integer, then 'y' into an integer, and dividing the two integer values, but surely there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = '4/10'
>>> float(eval(a))
0.4
```

But I would be careful with `eval` . It's not safe, you could probably use `ast.literal_eval()` instead

Comment: thank you for your answer! What issues could you run into by using only ' eval ' instead of  ' ast.literal_eval() '

Comment: I think this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197726/7024213